# calling legacy c functions from python

Tags: python-c-extension

I want to call legacy c third party functions from python.
I created a C api to make the function calls simpler.
In my python file
I tried to import the *.so for the api which links with the legacy code library.
But I kept seeing a libxxx ( the legacy c library) not found error.
I tried to import both ans still saw the same error.
I then tried using ctypes, but get the error ctypes not found.
Any suggestions ?

```
# python
Python 2.4.2 (#1, Apr 20 2012, 19:31:49)
[GCC 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named ctypes
>>> quit
```

Comment: ctypes can be downloaded for Python 2.3 and 2.4 from http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) only made it into the standard library in version 2.5, so 2.4 does not have it. I've also heard that some people exclude it when they build Python for a distribution or for embedding in a specific application, as you can easily crash your process using it, or even corrupt the host application's heap. But I have never encountered this myself, and I doubt a full installation does this.

As for not finding your C library, we'll need more details on that.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on the ctypes. Details on the c library: Built liba.so to call functions in libb.so. Liba.so links with lib.so.in my python file I just use import liba * Is that wrong ?

Comment: Python's `import` only imports other Python files and Python "extensions", which are dynamically linked libraries (.so on unix) with very specific requirements and written specifically for Python. You cannot import arbitrary libraries like that -- refer to the ctypes documentation for how to load those with ctypes.

Comment: Thanks delnan. The liba.so contains pthon specific c functions (accepts and returns PyObject *) and uses METHVARARGS. The only extra stuff that it does is it calls the 3rd party functions. Is that not supported ?

Comment: Well, this is turning into an entirely different question. Also, I have little knowledge about writing extensions. Why don't you ask that as a separate question?